# Identify renamed and modified file in Git using SHA1

Tags: c#, git, repository, low-level

I'm hacking around git repository at low-level, trying to retrieve file's history from it. And having difficulties identifying file modified and renamed in a same revision.

I'm developing C# application and I need to implement `git log --follow FILENAME` feature.

Modification is simple: search for file with given path in trees attached to revision, if SHA1 differs — *Voilà*!

Rename is simple too: if search by given path was not successful — look for object with same SHA1, as previously, if found — *Voilà*!

But if not found it might be either file deletion and my search is over, or rename and modify in same revision... but how to distinguish between these cases?

I've studied everything I found regarding Git internals, but still cannot find out what to do in this case, what might be common between tree objects corresponding to the same modified and renamed file in different revisions?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Git allready has that functionality. See `-M`/`--find-renames`, `-C`/`--find-copies` and `-C -C`/`--find-copies-harder` options to `diff` (applies to `log` and `show` as well) and `--follow` option to `log`.

The principle of `--find-renames` is, that if it sees new file in a revision, it looks at the files removed in that revision, compares them and if any is similar enough, declares it a rename.

**Edit**: In more details: To detect copies/renames, git compares the two revision first it compares the lists of files. Than for each path that only appears in the new revision it compares the content with content of files from old revision that `-M`—were deleted, `-C`—were modified or `-C`—all and if they are similar enough (which requires diff), marks it as rename or copy as appropriate. This is part of the diff core and is available to all commands that show diffs in any form, including the name-status, which does not do detailed line-by-line analysis. On top of this the `--follow` works by iterating the revisions one by one, does a name-status diff with rename detection and outputs the revision if the file was modified and remembers the new (old) name when it was renamed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this is not exactly what I'm looking for...

I need to implement this using C#. And I cannot use executable. 

I have access to the `.git` folder and I can retrieve some information using `libgit2sharp`. 

Can I find information about renames stored somewhere in repository?

Comment: @AlexeyShytikov: The information is never stored anywhere. If libgit2 does not implement the logic yet, you'll need to reimplement (see the second paragraph above) it. If you do, please consider doing it in C directly in libgit2 and contributing it back. Note, that libgit2 can't take code from git (because of more permissive license), but you can still look at how it's done in git.

Comment: Unfortunately libgit2 don't need this code: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/495 (and maybe they are right), so I plan to contribute to libgit2sharp https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/89 But it actually not so easy as it gets on a first look.

Comment: @AlexeyShytikov: Why do you think it does not *need* the code? Nobody stepped up to discuss it, which may be for many different reasons. And bindings (libgit2sharp) should be *bindings*. They should make functionality of the base library accessible, but not provide new functionality on top. The problem is that the functionality you need depends on the diff functionality and I don't see that in libgit2 at all.

Comment: Actually this is why: `I don't think the library should support it itself.` [via](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/495#issuecomment-2874800) And I agree, because following file history is not basic feature for  the library. Talking about `libgit2sharp` they do have some features on top of `libgit2` so it should be OK for them to bring file history feature to their object model.

Comment: @AlexeyShytikov: But that comment says it does not need "simplification", because it does not *do "filtering" now*. It does not say it shouldn't be doing filtering (you want filtering; simplification probably does not matter at this point). It should, but is not yet implemented. And the comparator, which it needs to be based on, is not implemented yet either.

Comment: Nevertheless, one way or another, I need to find out how it might be done. I picked C# as a language I know better, and when algorithm will be able to rewrite it on bare C.